# I cannot package webview2 together into a single executable file in my C# program

Tags: c#, webview2, fody-costura

I use costura.fody for packaging, although the packaging is successful, but I run the program, double-click the corresponding function point to trigger the event, webview2 does not work.

It's like I only drew a UI page, and didn't give it the actual function. In fact, the event of this function point is to pop up a new page and call webview2 to display information.

I also used some methods, such as embedding webview2-related files into my program and then packaging them. I also tried to change the configuration file of costura.fody, directly import the address of webview2 related files and then pack it. Actually, it doesn't help much. Read a lot of information, without exception, most of them have been tried.

**I tried the related library of embedded webview2, but it reported an error**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1752  Interop type 'WebView2' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.   data_view   C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\pro\Sharp_10_packeg\xxx\xxx_view.Designer.cs   102 Active


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1752  Interop type 'WebView2' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.   data_view   C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\pro\Sharp_10_packeg\xxx\xxx_view.Designer.cs   33  Active


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to delete file "bin\Release\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll". Access to the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\pro\Sharp_10_packeg\xxx\bin\Release\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll' is denied. xxx_view
```

*I have tried embedding webview2 into the program.*

*Also tried changing the address of webview2 in costura.fody.*

*Although these two methods can be compiled directly, webview2 still cannot be run, and the double-click event still does not respond, and there is no pop-up window*